# Changes should get happen in table while importing file in database

Tags: oracle

Is it possible that changes should get happen while importing the file in oracle database... Like there is already a record in a database and while importing the file there is an error that there is duplicacy of data however there should be something like this that the data should get update and there should be not duplicacy and no error...?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on *how* you are importing data.

I'd suggest you to use **external tables** feature.

- it (the external table) acts as if it was an "ordinary" table in the database
- its source is the file, located in a directory on the database server

  - which means that you'll have to create a directory (as an Oracle object) and grant privileges to user who will be using it
- as it acts as a table, you can write queries which use it
- moreover, you can use it in PL/SQL which allows you even better flexibility

Give it a try.

Comment: Simply just right click on the table name and select import option where we can cab file and can import the data in table

Comment: OK, and how will this "import option" handle duplicates and updates you mentioned?

Comment: That's the solution I want... How that import option will gonna handle the duplicates and updates.... Is there any option or possibility that we can handle that part....?

Comment: It will not. I already suggested what *will* (if you program it).